# Using LESS, can I reference a parent element in nested child elements

Tags: css, less

I have a table, with a header row and numerous data rows. I have a checkbox in the first column. In the `th` cell, I would like to add a top and bottom margin, on the `td` cells, I don't want this.

I have LESS(css) that is the same for both the `th` and `td` elements with class `.col-checkbox`, as well as a `label` element in both cells with shared css. I'd like to add the margin top/bottom to the label if it is in the `th` cell.

## .html file

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th class="col-checkbox">
            <div>Column Label</div>
            <label class="custom-checkbox">
                <input type="checkbox" />
                <span class="checkbox"></span>
            </label>
        </th>
        <th>
           Unimportant, there are more columns as well
        </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="col-checkbox">
            <label class="custom-checkbox">
                <input type="checkbox" />
                <span class="checkbox"></span>
            </label>
        </td>
        <td>
           Unimportant, there are more columns as well
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

## .less file

```
.col-checkbox {
    width: 30px;
    // more css here

    label.custom-checkbox {
         height: 24px;
         // more css here

        // I know I can do the following, but I'd like to not have to add
        // more classes if I can someone make this dependent on whether it 
        // is in the th or td element
        //&.header {
        //    margin: 6px auto;
        //}
        //
        //&.data {
        //    margin: 0 auto;
        //}
    }
}
```

I know I can make it work the way I have it above, but I was curious if I can do it just by referencing the `td` and `th` elements without duplicating the other css. I don't think so, but I figured I'd ask anyway.

Comment: You certainly can, makes the styles global, applicable to all tables with those elements.

Comment: I'm not exactly following you.

Comment: "I'd like to add the margin top/bottom to the label if it is in the th cell."
Is this what you are looking for?

`th > label`

(https://www.w3schools.com/csSref/sel_element_gt.asp)

So you select only the LABEL elements that are directly children of TH.

Comment: Ok, you are saying just pull it out of the nested format I have? I figured I was trying to make it harder than it should have been. Thanks

Comment: At quick glance what you're looking for is http://lesscss.org/features/#parent-selectors-feature-changing-selector-order. I.e. `th& {margin: 6px auto}`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you are already familiar with the `&` operator. Well it doesn't *have* to go before the selector. Instead, you can use it after the selector, such as `th&`, to get what you want.

So this:

```
.col-checkbox {
  width: 30px;
  // more css here

  label.custom-checkbox {
    height: 24px;
    // more css here
  }

  th& {
    margin: 10px 0;
  }
}
```

Outputs this:

```
.col-checkbox {
  width: 30px;
}
.col-checkbox label.custom-checkbox {
  height: 24px;
}
th.col-checkbox {
  margin: 10px 0;
}
```

However, a word of caution that this pattern may not work as you expect if you have more than one level of nesting.

Consider this code:

```
.col-checkbox {
  width: 30px;
  // more css here

  label.custom-checkbox {
    height: 24px;
    // more css here
    .checkbox& {
      color: navy;
    }
  }
}
```

You may expect to get this out of it:

```
.col-checkbox {
  width: 30px;
}
.col-checkbox label.custom-checkbox {
  height: 24px;
}
.col-checkbox label.custom-checkbox.checkbox {
  color: navy;
}
```

But in reality you'll get this:

```
.col-checkbox {
  width: 30px;
}
.col-checkbox label.custom-checkbox {
  height: 24px;
}
.checkbox.col-checkbox label.custom-checkbox {
  color: navy;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I was looking for. I did not realize I could use & after the selector.